# How to remove the top and bottom 8pt padding of the List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to reduce the default padding and inset of `List` to all zeros in SwiftUI.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    private let items = (0..<50).map { "Item \($0)" }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
            Text("Header")
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.pink)
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            Text("Footer")
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.pink)
        }
    }
}
```

When a list is given a header using `safeAreaInset()`, there is an 8pt padding between the list and the header.
When the list is scrolled to the end, there is a similar gap in the footer.

[image: 8pt padding]

I don't know where this padding comes from.
Is there any way to eliminate this padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white spaces are made by the `.safeAreaInset` modifier by default. You can remove them by specifying zero spacing in the modifier (`.safeAreaInset(edge: .top, spacing: .zero)` and `.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: .zero)`).

Complete code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    private let items = (0..<50).map { "Item \($0)" }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top, spacing: .zero) {
            Text("Header")
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.pink)
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: .zero) {
            Text("Footer")
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.pink)
                
        }
    }
}
```

[image: snapshot]